# Initial phase of Simple Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

Starting with the following solution for SHO:
$$x(t) = A\sin(\omega t+\varphi)\Rightarrow x_{0}=A\sin(\varphi)$$
$$\dot{x}(t) = v(t) = \omega A\cos(\omega t+\varphi) \Rightarrow v_{0}=\omega A\cos(\varphi)$$
I get the following initial phase:
$$\Rightarrow \tan(\varphi) = \frac{x_{0} \omega}{v_{0}}$$

But starting with:
$$x(t) = A\cos(\omega t+\varphi)\Rightarrow x_{0}=A\cos(\varphi)$$
which is a also a valid solution for the differential equation of the SMO,
$$\dot{x}(t) = v(t) = -\omega A\sin(\omega t+\varphi) \Rightarrow v_{0}=-\omega A\sin(\varphi)$$
I get this initial phase:
$$\Rightarrow \tan(\varphi) = -\frac{v_{0}}{x_{0} \omega}$$

Which one should be used? Are both correct?

Comment: If you are describing the motion with two different functions, then the phases at t = 0 will not be the same.

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations, you have discovered an identity. Since $$
\sin\left(x-{\pi\over2}\right)=-\cos x,\\
\cos\left(x-{\pi\over2}\right)=\sin x,
$$
I would write this identity as,
$$\tan\left(x-{\pi\over2}\right)={\sin\left(x-{\pi\over2}\right)
\over\cos\left(x-{\pi\over2}\right)}
=-\cot x,$$but of course you have found $-1/\tan x$ which is a valid expression for the same number.