# Why can you substitute $\cos\alpha=\frac A{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

**Problem**

Verify that the diﬀerential equation $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}= −k^2y$ has as its solution
$$y = A \cos (kx) + B \sin (kx)$$
where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary constants. Show also that this solution can be written in the form

$$y = C \cos (kx + \alpha) = C \Re[e^{j(kx+\alpha)}] = \Re[(Ce^{j\alpha})e^{jkx}]$$
and express $C$ and $\alpha$ as functions of $A$ and $B$.

**Solution**
$$y= A \cos(kx) + B \sin(kx)$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = −Ak \sin (kx) + Bk \cos (kx)$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = −Ak^2 \cos(kx)− Bk^2 \sin(kx) =−k^2[A \cos(kx) + B \sin(kx)]$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = −k^2y$$

Hence the given solution $y = A \cos(kx) + B \sin(kx)$ solves the given differential equation.

Now to express the equation in the desired form, we divide and multiply it by $\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}$. When we substitute $ \cos(\alpha) = \frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}}$ and $\sin(\alpha) = \frac{-B}{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}}$, the equation takes the desired form:

$$ y = \frac{A \cos(kx) + B \sin(kx)}{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}}\times\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}$$
$$ = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2}[\cos(\alpha)\cos(kx) - \sin(\alpha)\sin(kx)]$$
$$ = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2}\cos(kx + \alpha)$$

$$ y = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2}\cos(kx + \alpha) = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2}\Re[e^{j(kx + \alpha)}]= \Re[(\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}e^{j\alpha})e^{jkx}]$$

where

$$C = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2} \qquad\bigwedge\qquad \alpha = \tan^{-1}-\frac{B}{A}$$

**Inquiry**

The problem and solution of the harmonic motion equation above states that $\cos\alpha$ can be substitued with $$\frac A{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$$

Can anyone explain to me why is that substitution allowed?

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: The substitution is in the other direction. It is clear that $-1\leqslant\frac A{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\leqslant+1$ and so there must exist some angle $\alpha$ such that $\cos\alpha=\frac A{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$, and similarly for the other. Now, on top of that, the sum of squares of the two fractions is 1, which means that there exists a unique angle within a full circle in which both relations are simultaneously satisfied.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Thank you for your quick and helpfull reply! That's more or less the logic I was assuming in my head but I wanted to make sure. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: This question is going to be closed and abandoned fairly quickly; I know you already know the answer and won't need more. But next time, when you ask a question, try not to have just pictures. Type up the whole thing so that indexing works.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent thanks for the advice. This is my first question on physics exchange so I'm not very used to best practices just yet, but I will definitely try to format this question so it's not so painful to the eyes...

Comment: I have changed the format of the question. Let me know if it looks good to you. Thanks again!

Comment: It is very nice now.

Comment: Duplicates/closely related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/749280/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/305246/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/748285/226902